# Подключение файла в JAR через Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Пользуюсь средой разработки NetBeans. Собираю с помощью Ant.

Проблема заключается вот в чем: Например у меня есть какой-то проект с библиотеками в папке lib и некоторыми файлами в папке src. Объекты создаваемые в этом проекте используют данные библиотеки и файлы. Далее если я собираю данный проект в jar и кладу в библиотеку другого проекта, а потом использую объекты классов из данного jar то выпадает ислючение, что не хватает библиотек, либо файла по данному пути не существует. Соответственно, если добавить данные библиотеки и файлы в новый проект, то все работает. Но в jar они есть!!! Как сделать так чтобы объекты классов создаваемых из jar использовали данные ресурсы из своего jar?

Вот абстрактный пример:
Проект "А" из которого мы собираем jar и котором лежит файл hello.txt

```
package inner.ru;

import java.io.File;

public class Check {
     private final File file = new File("src//inner//file//hello.txt");

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(file.exists());
    }
}
```

Проект "B" в который в библиотеку мы кладем данный jar

```
 package external.main;

 import inner.ru.Check;

 public class Main {

     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Check check = new Check();
         check.print();
     }

}
```

Соответственно если во второй проект положить файл hello.txt, то получим true, но он уже лежит в первом проекте, и мне надо, чтобы он брал его именно оттуда.

Comment: Лучше разобрать на [конкретном примере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), сейчас непонятно что именно происходит. Попробуйте воспроизвести ошибку на двух проектах, убрать из них все лишнее и описать по шагам как воссоздать эти проекты.

Comment: Добавил абстрактный пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к файлу по относительному пути:

```
private final File file = new File("src//inner//file//hello.txt");
```

т.е. Вы ссылаетесь на файл, который лежит в папке `src\inner\file` относительно папки, в которой запущено приложение, а не к файлу, который запакован в JAR.

Когда Вы запускаете первый проект из Netbeans, он устанавливает текущую папку в корневой каталог проекта и код находит файл в папке исходников. Если Вы вытащите собранный JAR, перенесете его в отдельную папку и запустите его вручную там, то произойдет ошибка, т.к. папки `src` уже не будет. По той же причине ошибка возникает при запуске из второго проекта (файла нет в исходниках).

**Возможные решения:**

1. Указать абсолютный путь.

Вынести файл из проектов вообще и обращаться к нему по абсолютному пути (`c:\\Projects....\hello.txt`). В этом случае добавлять файл в JAR не нужно. При переносе скажем, на другую машину, файл потребуется носить отдельно, но так он будет доступен всем проектам.

2. Обращаться к файлу в JAR

Если файл находится в пакете `inner.file` то можно обращаться к запакованному файлу как к ресурсу. Например, вот так можно вывести содержимое файла:

```
public void print() {
    try (final InputStream stream = Check.class.getResourceAsStream("/inner/file/hello.txt")) {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(stream);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

Здесь обращение идет именно к файлу, запакованному в JAR и, соответственно, файл будет доступен при использовании из других проектов.

**Дополнение по библиотекам:**

Та же проблема возникает с библиотеками. Используемые библиотеки не собираются в результирующий JAR файл. Соответственно, если проект `inner` использует библиотеку `dependency.jar`, которая не включена в проект `external` то при обращении к методам `inner`, которые зависят от `dependency` будут выброшены исключения.

Возможные решения:

1. Переносить вместе с JAR-файлом все его библиотеки.

Т.е. если `external` использует `inner`, то в него нужно добавить `dependency.jar`. При таком точечном подходе возможно более гибкое использование библиотек. Например, `external` может использовать более новую версию `dependency`, в этом случае может быть ненужно таскать за `inner` старые версии.

Посмотрите также на системы управления зависимостями: например, [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) или [Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/). Они существенно упрощают работу с библиотеками при сборке.

2. Собрать все зависимости в один JAR.

Можно также собрать `inner` таким образом, чтобы в одном JAR содержались все необходимые библиотеки.

Сделать это можно так:

1. Открыть файл `build.xml` — это скрипт сборки Ant, который находится в корне проекта. В Netbeans он отображается в окне «Файлы».
2. Добавить в конец скрипта следующую цель:

```xml
<target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">

    <!-- Замените MyJarName на имя, соответствуюее Вашему JAR
    -->
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>


    <!-- don't edit below this line -->

    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

</target>
```

3. После этого раскрыть `build.xml` и найти цель «`package-for-store`».
4. Нажать на цель правой кнопкой и запустить ее.
5. В корне проекта в папке `store` должен появиться JAR, с упакованными в него зависимостями. Его можно использовать в других проектах.

Смотрите также:

- Урок со скриншотами из которого взят код выше — [Use NetBeans IDE 6.7 to Combine JAR Files Into a Single JAR File](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-139904.html)
- Обсуждение в английской версии — [Netbeans Export to Jar, include all library files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505057/netbeans-export-to-jar-include-all-library-files)

Comment: Спасибо, то что было нужно, с файлами все работает. Подскажите еще, может есть возможность как-то добавить и библиотеки. Они у меня лежат в отдельном пакете в данном проекте. Потом в папке lib я выбираю добавление данных jar. Но когда мы кладем jar данного проекта в другой проект, то осуществляется поиск этих jar в lib нового проекта?

Comment: @hmeli7 Дополнил ответ информацией по библиотекам

Answer (score 0):

Я при использовании Ant добавляю зависимые библиотеки и в один и в другой проект, то есть:
есть библиотека Y,
есть проект A,
который использует проект B,
который в свою очередь использует Y.
Я добавляю Y и к A и к B.
Вся фишка в том, как именно происходит сборка, например, если вы используете настройки Ant Netbeans по умолчанию, то зависимые библиотеки складываются в папку lib относительно основного jar файла и так прописываются в манифесте.
Если же вы подключаете другой проект как зависимый, jar файл этого проекта просто указывается библиотекой и так же помещается в папку lib.
Соответственно в манифесте проекта B указывается lib как папка с библиотеками для него, но этой папки нет, так как сам подключаемый jar проекта B уже лежит в lib. 
Думаю, если Вам не хочется дублировать библиотеки, то зависимый проект B стоит собирать как один jar файл с упаковкой библиотек в него.

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Что надо изменить в файле манифеста проекта А, чтобы при создании объектов классов из данного проекта подтягивались зависимости из данного проекта, а не из проекта В?